# Variable is accessed from within inner class , needs to be declared final

Tags: android, checkbox, inner-classes, final

I am using multiple check boxes and need to perform different operations on checked i.e increment some static variables according to the checkbox selected.

So the problem is i cant make the variable i to be final (using a loop) , otherwise it is not accessible in the inner class.
Is there any solution i could work around ?

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)

    {
        int ids = Integer.parseInt("R.id.s" + i);

        seats[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids);
        seats[i].setWidth(15);
        seats[i].setHeight(16);

        seats[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(i<=33)
                    SelectSeat.ROYAL++;

                if(i<=77 && i>33)
                SelectSeat.PLAT++;

                else
                    SelectSeat.GOLD++;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)

    {
        int ids = Integer.parseInt("R.id.s" + i);

        seats[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids);
        seats[i].setWidth(15);
        seats[i].setHeight(16);

        final int finalI = i;
        seats[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(finalI <=33)
                    SelectSeat.ROYAL++;

                if(finalI <=77 && finalI >33)
                    SelectSeat.PLAT++;

                else
                    SelectSeat.GOLD++;
            }
        });
    }
```

This should solve your problem.

What I did here is copy your `i` into a final int `finalI` in each loop, and used `finalI` instead of `i` in the inner class.

Comment: Quick and easy fix , Thanks (y)